# Count number of posts of each user - SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I need to get the number of posts each user has created.
This is the structure of both tables (users, microposts).

Microposts

- id
- user_id
- content
- created_at

Users

- id
- name
- email
- admin

---

```
SELECT users.*, count( microposts.user_id ) 
FROM microposts LEFT JOIN users ON users.id=microposts.user_id 
GROUP BY microposts.user_id
```

This gets me only the users that have posts. I need to get all users, even if they have 0 posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the join in the wrong order.

In a `LEFT JOIN` you ensure you keep all the records in the table written first *(to the left)*.

So, join in the other order *(`users` first/left)*, and then group by the user table's id, and not the microposts table's user_id...

```
SELECT users.*, count( microposts.user_id ) 
FROM users LEFT JOIN microposts ON users.id=microposts.user_id 
GROUP BY users.id
```

Comment: Awesome. Worked as intended. Thanks :)